# CURL で取得したテキストをスクリプトとして実行したい

Tags: linux, shellscript

Webにテキストデータとしてアップロードしたスクリプトを CURLで取得して実行したいです。

URL
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8763485/stackoverflow.sh
内容:
`echo ':)'`

にアップロードしたテキストを curl でダウンロードして実行したいです

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ソース

`curl -sf https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8763485/stackoverflow.sh | sh -s`

出力
`:)`

これでいかがでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

bash以外のshell入っても実行できます。

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8763485/stackoverflow.sh)"
```

curl:
-f, --fail
サーバエラーが生じたときに黙って（何も出力しないまま）終わらせます。
-s, --silent
沈黙モードにします。
-S, --show-error
失敗時にはエラーメッセージが表示されるようになります。
-L, --location
サイトからクッキーと location が送信されてくる場合、次のように存在しないファイルを与えて，「クッキーの意識的処理」を起動させられる。

sh:
-c シェルスクリプトを実行出来る。